# Understanding Mosaic to New Raster treatment of pixel values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic, tools

I'm working with arcGIS.

I have mosaicked 8 rasters with values ranging from -408 to 180. The new mosaic shows pixel values ranging from 0 to 180.Then I compared cell by cell values from the original 8 rasters to the new one, and they match. (The values in the new raster are just integers and decimals in the original rasters, but values in both are very close, rounded to the next integer). However, the negative values are gone in the new raster.

How does this tool treats pixel values from original rasters and target raster?